What is an appropriate NDIS driver stack to control two slave NICs by one master virtual NIC?
What is the recommended architecture for a network driver stack for my use case - where I want to present a NIC (virtual, master) which controls two slave NICs (real, physical). The master will duplicate outgoing frames to both the slaves, and receive frames from both the slaves, and pass them up the stack to the protocols.
It seems like I need to use some combination of filter, intermediate and miniport drivers. Just looking for suggestions on what the appropriate arrangement is and how it might be implemented, installed and configured.

A MUX-IM driver is the traditional way to do this. The classic LBFO (NIC Teaming) feature included in Windows Server uses this architecture.
You could also cobble it together with a filter (aka LWF) and a miniport, but that would be somewhat less ideal.
This is not a simple project — please make sure you are prepared to spend a significant amount of time learning NDIS fundamentals and debugging your driver. For example, each offload needs to be handled separately. (What do you do if your virtual NIC claims to support TCP Checksum Offload, but only one of the physical NICs supports it? How do you merge RSS indirection tables?) NDIS does not synchronize IM drivers as much as it does for other types of drivers, so you're responsible for synchronizing datapath state of the member NICs: if one member is paused or disabled, what happens to the other NICs?
MUX-IM drivers also require a NetCfg Notify Object to set up bindings and prevent circular bindings. These are a little tricky to write, and you should test it interops with other IM drivers, like virtual switches and classic LBFO.
If possible, I suggest finding an existing off-the-shelf solution, rather than building your own. If you do opt to build your own, the muxim sample can get you started.
